# Persisting with FileManager is producing unique urls at every app launch in Simulator

Tags: swift, storage, ios-simulator, persistence, nsfilemanager

I want to persist data, images and otherwise.  I read that saving to files is especially recommended for larger data.  I followed relevant parts of this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/persisting-data.

However, the URL in the way mentioned, every time I launch, it produces a new url.

```swift
public extension FileManager {
    func with(hash: String) throws -> URL {
        try url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathExtension(hash)
    }
}
```

Then when I call this:

```swift
let localURL: URL = try! FileManager.default.with(hash: deterministicHash + "downloadData")
print(localURL.absoluteString)
```

Produces this on the first launch:

```
file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/376FF910-242B-4E2E-9E32-F9CE845EB1BE/data/Containers/Data/Application/3B28DBA9-8C2E-4CE5-A92A-F4C4DDB106AC/Documents.downloadData/
```

And this on the second:

```
file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/376FF910-242B-4E2E-9E32-F9CE845EB1BE/data/Containers/Data/Application/5F5EC7DC-2A41-402C-8265-EF99F50D2C90/Documents.downloadData/
```

I just want to persist data that can securely accommodate images.  How can I either get a consistent url to use? Or otherwise get around this issue?

**UPDATE**
I implemented this tutorial:
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/persisting-data
Even after following this tutorial, I am not able to persist.  Is there a computer setting I need to enable/disable?

Answer (score 0):

The issue there is that your app is sandboxed. Just don’t save the whole url. What you need is to save the directory and file name and reconstruct your URL at every launch. Btw you should use pathComponent not pathExtension when composing your URL.

```
try url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent(hash)
```